# On Bachet's Duplication Formula and the number $-432$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

While reading "Rational Points on Elliptic Curves" by Silverman and Tate, I came across this interesting passage about Bachet's duplication formula:

[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot]

I know how to derive Bachet's duplication formula using the tangent method (namely, one constructs a tangent line to a given rational point on this cubic. The third intersection point of the line and the cubic gives the new rational point). My question is about the mysterious $-432$.

> Why is it true that if the original rational solution $(x, y)$ has $xy\neq 0$ and if
>   $c\neq 1, -432$, then repeating this process leads to infinitely many
>   distinct solutions?

**Edit.**  Later in the book (page 24), there is a explicit calculation that puts the cubic $u^3+v^3=\alpha$ into Weierstrass Normal Form. The resulting equation is $y^2=x^3-432\alpha^2$. So in particular, $y^2=x^3-432$ is Weierstrass Normal Form of $x^3+y^3=1$. So perhaps this explains the appearance of $-432$ above?

[image]

Comment: What must happen is that when $c=-432$ the point $(x,y)=(12,36)$ is in the 3-torsion, so the duplication formula (I'm fairly sure that your formula actually calculates $[-2]P$ given that $(12,36)$ is a fixed point) fails to produce a new point. On the other hand, if the point $P=(x,y)$ is of infinite order, then all the generated points: $[-2]P, [4]P, [-8]P,\ldots$ are necessarily distinct. IIRC there are methods for finding the rational torsion points of an elliptic curve. Must be the case that none exist outside the coordinate axes unless $c$ has one of those values.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thanks for the idea. I suppose [Nagell-Lutz theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagell–Lutz_theorem) could be helpful here.

Comment: The curves $y^2 = x^3 - 1$ and $y^2 = x^3 - 432$ and the only elliptic curves of the form $y^2 = x^3 + c$ with torsion points over the rationals where $x$ and $y$ are not $0$..  For other choices of $c$ a point with $x$ and $y$ nonzero has infinite order.

Comment: @KCd: Thanks! I believe that, but would you happen to know a reference that proves this result? The hard part is, of course, to prove the statement for all $c\neq 1, -432$.

Comment: We need the convention that $c$ is not divisible by a 6th power, since for any nonzero integer $m$ the equations $y^2 = x^3 + c$ and $y^2 = x^3 + m^6c$ are easily transformed into each other by a rational change of variables, so their rational solutions are in a simple bijection. It's for *sixth-power free* integers $c$ that $y^2 = x^3 + c$ has torsion points with nonzero $x$ and $y$ only when $c = 1$ or $-432$. In any event, I think this is discussed in the little book by Cassels on elliptic curves. It's mentioned as Prop. 17.10.1 in Ireland & Rosen. See also Prop 17.9.1 in Ireland & Rosen.

Comment: @KCd: That 6th power part makes sense :) And thank you very much for the references! In Cassels, it is Theorem on page 52 that classifies torsion points for $y^2=x^3+c$ for $c$ non-6th power, and answers my question! And I shall take a look at Ireland & Rosen when I am at the library. Please consider converting your last comment into an answer, so I can upvote and accept it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need the convention that $c$ is not divisible by a $6$th power, since for any nonzero integer $m$ the equations $y^2=x^3+c$ and $y^2 =x^3 +m^6 c$ are easily transformed into each other by a rational change of variables, so their rational solutions are in a simple bijection. It's for sixth-power free integers $c$ that $y^2 =x^3 +c$ has torsion points with nonzero $x$ and $y$ only when $c=1$ or $−432$. In any event, I think this is discussed in the little book by Cassels on elliptic curves. It's mentioned as Prop. 17.10.1 in Ireland & Rosen. See also Prop 17.9.1 in Ireland & Rosen.